Improving PyTesseract text extraction quality
I am working on an OCR project where I need to extract text from images. How can I improve text extraction quality in python.
The OCR sometimes fails to detect small text in the image.
The OCR output occasionally includes unrelated text from the background.
image
def preprocess_image(image_path):
    # Load image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    if image is None:
        print("Error: Unable to load image.")
        return None

    # Resize image to a larger size
    resized_image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=2, fy=2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Enhance contrast
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8))
    enhanced = clahe.apply(gray)

    # Adaptive thresholding
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(enhanced, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

    # # Apply morphological operations
    # kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
    # morphed = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

    return thresh, resized_image

